# Using fnRender with ajax source datatable

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jquery, datatables

I was trying just modifying one of the examples to do customize a cell:

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "sources/deep.txt",
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mDataProp": "engine" },
                    { "fnRender": function( oObj ) {
                                    return "Test";
                                } },
                    { "mDataProp": "platform.inner" },
                    { "mDataProp": "platform.details.0" },
                    { "mDataProp": "platform.details.1" }
                ]
            } );
```

Which uses a source like:

```
{ "aaData": [
{
    "engine": "Trident",
    "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
    "platform": {
        "inner": "Win 95+",
        "details": [
            "4",
            "X"
        ]
    }
},
...
...
```

Data is displayed correctly but I started getting "DataTables warning (table id = 'example'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0"

Anything I'm missing? Or I should be doing this in a different way?

Comment: Can you setup this case in http://jsfiddle.net/ so that it will be easy for us to look at?

Comment: I've tried to setup using jsfiddle but I cannot get the json response to work there [jsfiddle.net/uuefn/](http://jsfiddle.net/uuefn/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With help of official support I found the answer:

An additional parameter needs to be defined in order to avoid that alert:

```
{                "sDefaultContent": "",
                 "fnRender": function( oObj ) {
                               return "Test";
} }
```

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/9030/using-fnrender-with-ajax-source-datatable#Item_1

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure thatyour error isn't here

```
                { "mDataProp": "platform.details.0" },
                { "mDataProp": "platform.details.1" }
```

that should be

```
                { "mDataProp": "platform.details[0]" },
                { "mDataProp": "platform.details[1]" }
```

since details is an array?

Comment: Nope it is perfectly valid to use just the number there.